# Is it possible to programmatically alter a USB<->Serial converter's 'BM' latency option?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, serial-port

Is there any way to programmatically alter the 'BM Options Latency Timer' of a USB<->Serial adapter? Needs to work on embedded windows xp. Can be a .net 2.0 or native windows solution...

[image]

Comment: If you can’t wait for an answer (this kind of question can take months...) try this: run [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), change the setting, see if there is any obviously related registry or disk actvitiy.

Comment: If you add that as an answer I'll upvote it and give it a shot :-)

Comment: I don’t usually post that kind of thing as answers, even if it does end up being helpful :)

Comment: It's times like this when I wish there was a way of accepting multiple answers. A bit of probing with ProcMon reveals this gets set when I change the value in device manager: `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+A600fcUkA\0000\Device Parameters\LatencyTimer`. Thankyou very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using an FTDI USB serial converter. Then you can use [libftdi](http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/documentation/group__libftdi.html#ga3e0227b0c7aa859d2d2afb5ffa4c8466)

And check out the [Application Notes](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes.htm) (especially AN232B-04) because they contain lots of useful information.

Comment: As it happens, it does appear to be an FTDI chip inside (an FT232RL).

Comment: @Jon Cage: Then also check out the [application notes](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes.htm). Especially AN232B-04. In section 3.2 it tells you how to preconfigure the latency.

Comment: Accepted: those application notes look excellent. Not sure whether I'll use libftdi or go straight to the registry yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is driver specific. Your best bet is to do what romkyns says and try to figure out where the driver stores this setting. You will probably need to close and reopen the serial port after changing the setting assuming you are able to find out how it is stored and are able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016, the advice in AN232B-04 may be outdated due to changes in the Windows driver infrastructure. Nowadays, there's a requirement to sign all files in a driver package, which means that editing values in a inf/cat file while otherwise using the stock FTDI driver is not possible without re-signing the driver.

If you're using libftdi, you can configure this value at runtime, as per rve's answer. If you prefer to use FTDI's own driver and Windows' standard COM port API, and you need to configure this value, you can still change it permanently and programmatically by editing the registry.

If you go this route, you need to change the DWORD value `LatencyTimer` under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+KBxxxxxxx\0000\Device Parameters`. `KBxxxxxxx` in this example needs to be replaced by the serial number of your device. You would need higher privileges to change this value, eg by raising a UAC prompt. The device driver may need to be restarted at that point for the changes to take effect, for example by unplugging and replugging the device.